# undefined method `options=' for true:TrueClass

Tags: methods, undefined, nomethoderror

I made a typo in the section {} portion of my custom.css.scss file and saved.  Then changed it back to how it originally was and saved again.

THEN, when I refreshed my browser I received the error message title "NoMethodError in Static_pages#home "

The next detail it gives is:

Showing /Users/luthermoore/Documents/rails_projects/nest/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `options=' for true:TrueClass
  (in /Users/luthermoore/Documents/rails_projects/nest/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)

Extracted source (around line#5) ***The "stylesheet_link_tag" line as listed below.

`<html>` 
`<head>`
`<title>NesT</title>`
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>`
`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`
`<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`
`</head>`

****When I take out the whole "stylesheet_link_tag" line above completely from the application.html.erb file and refresh it looks like plain html but if I put it back it gives me the same error message again.  I've looked at another sample project I have with the EXACT SAME applications.html.erb head and it works fine.  I've tried deleting, saving, rewriting, saving.  And I've also tried deleting, copying from the application.html.erb file that DOES work and saving again and the error message will not go away.

I'm running everything pretty new and just installed a couple weeks ago...
Rails 3.2.8
Ruby 1.9.3
Bootstrap-sass 2.2.1.1

Please help.  If you can't tell from my explanation, I'm pretty green when it comes to coding.  I tried to be as detailed as possible but if you need more info from me please let me know.

Comment: This happens to me as well. The only thing that was changed recently was unicorn, from thin. Wondering if you have managed to get this working

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting things in your apps' /tmp/cache folder